# How long does it take for an object to slide down an inclined plane?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

Suppose you have an object that is at height h and slides down a length l. How long does it take to slide this distance?

From my understanding, on an inclined plane, $s=\frac{1}{2}sin(\theta)\alpha t^2$, Hence, $l=\frac{1}{2}sin(\theta)\alpha t^2$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the plane and $\alpha$ is the downward acceleration.

The answer provided is $\frac{l}{4\sqrt{h}}$ But I do not know how to get to this expression.

Comment: Please do not use $a$ and $\alpha$ in the same expressions.  And you mean downward acceleration, not force. Where did your "from my understanding" formula come from?

Comment: I am using "Calculus: An intuitive and physical approach", the description of that formula is as thus; The estimation of distance using an acceleration that is directly downward is $s=\frac{1}{2}\alpha t^2$. On an inclined plane, the strength of that acceleration is estimated from breaking up the acceleration into two parallel forces, $f_1$ and $f_2$. If $f_1$ acts along the plane, then we use $sin(\theta)$ to determine the value of this acceleration along the plane, hence $s=\frac{1}{2}sin(\theta)\alpha t^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a coordinate system with the $x$-axis parallel to the slope, you get according to Newton's second law:

$$mx^{\prime \prime}(t) = m \alpha \sin \theta$$ where $\alpha$ is the gravity.

And therefore $x(t) = \frac{1}{2} \alpha \sin \theta t^2$ if the object starts at time $t=0$ at the origin of the coordinate system with no velocity. You have $\frac{h}{l} = \sin \theta$.

We're looking for $T$ such that $x(T) = l$ which means

$$l=  \frac{1}{2} \alpha \frac{h}{l} T^2$$ and finally

$$T = l \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha h}}$$

...and I don't understand where the expression you were given is coming from. By the way, if I understood correctly the question, if $\theta = \pi/2$ you get $l=h$ and the expression I got is coherent with a free falling motion.

Comment: I agree with your derivation. The given answer cannot be correct, because time does not have units of $\sqrt{\text{length}}$.